# Installing kernel 3.8 on 12.10, 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, kernel

He there,

the release notes for kernel 3.8 do mention improved performance for ext4 using small files. That alone sounds interesting; now I am wondering: will there be a simple PPA approach at some point that allows to use 3.8 kernels on 12.10 (and/or maybe 12.04)?

In the sense of: I just add the ppa once; and then like with "normal" kernels I dont need to worry about any updates, they just come along without any further activity on my side?

Or does using upstream kernels imply that I have to fetch out myself any time a new 3.8 versions comes around the corner?

Comment: the kernel is a different beast than an app. Yeah you can fetch it anytime a new version comes out, but then you have to compile and configure EVERYTHING yourself. If you have an itch for that, I recommend "Linux from scratch" it's a great learning experience. PPA for the kernel? not happening.

Comment: @phipsalabim - The ubuntu kernel team provides .deb for the mainline kernel. See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Comment: I love making an idiot of myself. Note to everyone that uses the Internet: Never listen to anything that I say. thanks bodhi, that's pretty awesome.

Comment: If you use alsa dont install it. I have no sound now and I get some lib error involving the new kernel if I use `sudo alsa force-reload`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The DEB Packages for the 3.8 (And any other kernel version) can be found here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

For 3.8 alone you can see them here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8-raring/

Be careful since using a kernel version not tested on a specific version of Ubuntu can have bad results, from Drivers not working to problems booting. Even kernel panic could occur. In most cases it will work correctly but just so you have that in mind when applying a kernel not tested to an older Ubuntu version (In this case 3.8 is for 13.04).

For additional information see:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Answer (score 4):

As 3.8 is very very new, you'll have to fetch is yourself, for now. That said, you can expect 3.8 to make it into 12.04 repositories through backporting, in the similar manner the 3.5 kernel from 12.10 did. 12.10 is not an LTS release, and therefore will remain with its original 3.5 kernel untill the end.

To illustrate what I am talking about, check out the available kernels from [10.10, 11.04 and 11.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image-generic-lts&searchon=names&suite=lucid&section=all) in Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 4):

Currently you can upgrade to 3.8 from main repositories.

Today after running:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-raring
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-lts-raring
```

Reboot.

`uname -a` returned `3.8.0-32-generic # 47-precise1-ubuntu`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

The repos now includes saucy as well:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-saucy
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-lts-saucy
```

Reboot.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```